# Out-of-order execution in C#

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

I have the following snippet:

```cs
static long F(long a, long b, long c, long d) 
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

which generates:

```
<Program>$.<<Main>$>g__F|0_0(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int64)
    L0000: add rdx, rcx
    L0003: lea rax, [rdx+r8]
    L0007: add rax, r9
    L000a: ret
```

If I understand correctly from [this](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) (**§ Out of order execution**) manual: The code above translates to `((a + b) + c) + d`. And to compute this the CPU has to wait for the 1st parenthesis and for the 2nd and so on. In here we see that `LEA` is in the middle which means that they can't be executed in parallel (if I understood that correctly). So what the writer suggests is:

writing parenthesis on "independent" pairs:

```cs
static long G(long a, long b, long c, long d) 
{
    return (a + b) + (c + d);
}
```

but this generates the same assembly:

```
<Program>$.<<Main>$>g__G|0_1(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int64)
    L0000: add rdx, rcx
    L0003: lea rax, [rdx+r8]
    L0007: add rax, r9
    L000a: ret
```

In contrast this is what `GCC (O2)` generates for `C` code:

```c
int64_t
f(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t c, int64_t d) {
        return a + b + c + d;
}

int64_t
g(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t c, int64_t d) {
        return (a + b) + (c + d);
}
```

here is the output:

```
f: 
        add     rcx, rdx        ; I guess -O2 did the job for me.
        add     rcx, r8         ; I guess -O2 did the job for me.
        lea     rax, [rcx+r9]
        ret
g:
        add     rcx, rdx
        add     r8, r9
        lea     rax, [rcx+r8]
        ret
```

## Question

- Did I understand the manual correctly? Should the 2 `ADD`s come with each other (no `LEA` in the middle)? If yes how can I hint the `C#` compiler to not ignore my parenthesis?

#### Notes

- Here is the [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABARiQAIAbCAOwHMKAxAChoYuzWrseG/aMwA3hQAmASgoBYAFABvORWUViAdk4UA1BWDaKYfWIDccgL5y5ZSoIoBxNqK48O/F0JEdJMhUpXqKFmx9YCkdFkMdSVNZMyA==) link.
- Here is the [Gotbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rf5TG4TnK) link.

Comment: Integer addition is associative; your parentheses are semantically irrelevant. The C# compiler will translate it to IL straightforwardly (so respecting your order, more or less) but the JIT compiler then still rearranges that IL to code as it best sees fit, and if there is an improvement to be made, this should certainly not depend on where you happened to put parentheses. C# is not C++.

Comment: To really understand what is happening you need to look at the Intel microprocessor manual and understand the pipelining inside the microprocessor.  The compiler will optimize the code, but the microprocessor still may change order in the pipeline.

Comment: @JeroenMostert what we're looking at is the native final `ASM`, don't we? I don't understand the "rearranges that IL to code as it best sees fit" part. Shouldn't the `LEA` be under the last `ADD`? Did I misunderstood the manual? How can the first one be executed in parallel? If you could explain me I would be extremely thankfull.

Comment: @jdweng Is there a predictable way of looking at code and saying that X will be rearranged but Y not?

Comment: My point is: I have no idea if the `LEA` needs to be under the `ADD` for performance reasons because I'm not a JIT compiler writer, but I do know that if it does need to be there, it should not depend on how you write the addition in C#, but folded as a quality improvement in the JIT compiler instead. And there are [many such improvements still to be made](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=label%3Atenet-performance), C++ compilers have a massive head start there.

Comment: Note that your document talks specifically about floats, where the order of operations *does* matter (floating-point operations are not associative). Your example is about ints, which is different. I don't know, but I would assume the CPU is smart enough to re-order integer additions (which is after all one of the most basic re-orderings a CPU can do), making your C# and C++ ASM listings equivalent.

Comment: Notice how the placement of the parens *does* affect the ASM here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABARiQAIAzAGwmwwoDEAKW+x7Nauhi4buz5hBvRgBMAlBQCwAKADe8iiorEA7BWwUA1P10UwB8QG55AX3nyylIYwDibMVtEd+r4R4nT5SuarVNFm09YGk9FiM9KTM5cyA=

Comment: @canton7 `int`s are even better, aren't they? Why should the compiler not take advantage of `int`s?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Even better". My point is that the order of the ADD and LEA for ints is probably utterly irrelevant: the CPU is going to re-order them in the most efficient way *anyway* (I'd assume), so there's no point in the JIT emitting one ordering rather than the other. The JIT/compiler is therefore free to elide your parens, and compile the versions with and without parens in the same way. However the order of evaluation *does* matter for floats, and the JIT/compiler needs to respect the parens you added in order to preserve correctness

Comment: @canton7 then I'd say I'm back to the question that I asked to `jdweng`:  Is there a predictable way of looking at code and saying that X will be rearranged but Y not? And by "event better" I mean that compiler knows that `int`s are associative so it can reorder the instructions (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: That's a resounding "no" unless you're very familiar with the architecture of the particular processor you're using, in which case it probably gets upgraded to "maybe". It's not that they will be re-ordered, it's that they may be re-ordered or (more likely) run in parallel, depending on what else is going on at the time, which execution units are free, etc. At the end of the day, modern CPUs are so complex that the only sure way to get accurate numbers on things like this is through benchmarks

Comment: @Hrant It *has* re-ordered them: it's treated the versions with and without parens the same :) Maybe it hasn't re-ordered them in the way you expect, but my point is that it almost certainly doesn't matter, so why would it bother?

Comment: @canton7 `C/C++` compilers are beasts at optimizing. If they consistently put `LEA` under/above 2 `ADD`s wouldn't that mean that there's something to it? "why would it bother": I'm trying to understand the tools I use. I think it's more fun than using X or Y library without knowing the internals. c:

Comment: The way to find out is through benchmarking :) For example, that might simply be a holdover from the days before superscalar CPUs. Also remember that C/C++ compilers have all the time in the world to run every optimization known to man, but the JIT has to be lightening fast. There's therefore a trade-off in the JIT: just looking for an optimization might take more of the user's time than would ever be saved by performing it. If it's quicker overall not to bother putting the LEA after the ADD, it won't

Comment: Also fun: select Clang in gotbolt: that does add, lea, add. MSVC does lea, add, add, but in a way where there's a data dependency between each of those instructions.

Comment: It's less "All C/C++ compilers do it this way", and more "C/C++ compilers do it every possibly way"!

Comment: @JeroenMostert: There is a semantic difference if overflow checking is enabled, right?  One grouping might overflow while another would not.

Comment: The order here doesn't matter, because the same registers are used, so one instruction will be stalled anyway. Mathematically both versions are aequivalent, so the result is correct.

Comment: Both the slower and the faster versions (in terms of latency - there's no difference in throughput) could be written as `lea add add`, `add lea add`, and as `add add lea`, that doesn't make any difference, the difference is in their dependency graph (either allowing the first two instructions to be executed in parallel, or not)

Comment: If you enable checked arithmetic, then yes the JIT preserves order, but it also inserts a ton of other instructions to check for overflow.

Comment: `nicomp`, `Devolus` ah, ok. Now I get it. Thank you. I thought the order matters.

Comment: @canton7 weird, all compilers I tested `ICC`, `GCC`, `CLANG`, `MSVC` they don't put `LEA` in the middle. But as others said: the dependency graph is important and not the ordering.

Comment: @NateEldredge: yes, I should have said *unchecked* integer addition is associative; most developers (me included) tend to forget .NET has checked math since it's so rarely used (let alone as the default). For this case it doesn't really matter since the JIT knows to operate under different rules if you're doing checked math; in this case it's clearly free to output instructions as it sees fit.

Comment: @canton7: The dependency pattern in the asm *does* matter.  Out-of-order execution doesn't try to re-associate associative operations like integer add.  GCC has silly missed-optimizations with signed `int64_t` - the fact that signed-overflow is UB in C seems to be stopping it from treating it as associative.  Using `uint64_t` allows it to optimize both ways properly: two independent adds, then combine pairs. https://godbolt.org/z/W13WEjjMh. Clang defeats itself both ways, serializing the operations like C#'s JIT does, even if you hint it in the source to use more instruction-level parallelism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Integer addition is associative.**  Compilers *can* take advantage of this (the "as-if rule"), regardless of the source-level order of operations.

(Unfortunately it seems most compilers are doing a bad job at this and making it worse even if you write your source cleverly.)

There's no side-effect for integer overflow in asm; even on targets like MIPS where `add` traps on signed-overflow, compilers use `addu` which doesn't, so they can optimize.  (In C, compilers *can* assume the source-level order of operations never overflows, because that would be Undefined Behaviour.  So they *could* use trapping `add` on ISAs that have it, for calculations that happen with the same inputs in the C abstract machine. But even though `gcc -fwrapv` to give signed-integer overflow well-defined 2's complement wraparound behaviour is *not* the default, compilers do use instructions that may allow silent wrapping, not trapping.  Mostly so they don't have to care about whether any given operation is on values that appear in the C abstract machine or not. UB doesn't mean required-to-fault; `-fsanitize=undefined` takes extra code to make that happen.)

e.g. `INT_MAX + INT_MIN + 1` could be evaluated as `INT_MAX + 1` (overflowing to INT_MIN), then `. + INT_MIN` overflowing back to 0 on a 2's complement machine, or in source order with no overflows.  Same final result, and that's all that's logically visible from the operation.

---

**CPUs with out-of-order exec don't try to re-associate instructions, though, they follow the dependency graph from the asm / machine code.**

(For one thing, that's too much for hardware to consider on the fly, and for another, the FLAGS output of each operation *does* depend on which temporaries you create, and an interrupt could arrive at any point.  So the proper architectural state needs to be recoverable at instruction boundaries when all older instructions have finished.  **That means it's the compiler's job to expose [instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) in the asm**, not for the hardware to use math to create it.  See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) and [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024))

---

### So how did compilers do?

**Mostly badly**, shooting themselves in the foot / pessimizing your attempt at doing this source-level optimization, at least in this case.

- C#: removes ILP even if it exists in the source; serializes `(a+b) + (c+d)` into one linear chain of operations; 3 cycle latency.
- clang12.0: same, serializes both versions.
- MSVC: same, serializes both versions.
- GCC11.1 for signed `int64_t`: preserves source order of operations. It's a longstanding GCC missed-optimization bug that its optimizer avoids introducing signed-overflow even in temporaries for some reason, like it backwards as far as the promises / guarantees / optimization opportunities that something being UB in the abstract machine creates when making a concrete implementation that runs *as if* on the abstract machine.  Although GCC *does* know it can auto-vectorize `int` addition; it's only reordering within a scalar expression where some overly-conservative check lumps signed integer in with floating-point as non-associative.
- GCC11.1 for `uint64_t` or with `-fwrapv`: treats as associative and compiles `f` and `g` the same way.  Serializes with most tuning options (including for other ISAs like MIPS or PowerPC), but `-march=znver1` happens to create ILP.  (This does *not* mean that only AMD Zen is superscalar, it means GCC has missed-optimization bugs!)
- ICC 2021.1.2: creates ILP even in the linear source version (`f`), but uses add/mov instead of LEA as the final step. :/

**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qgA%2BjtTkxnVEQINq2epgDC6dgFcAtvRAB2cucwAZAvWwA5BwBG2KQgABzkAA7oIsQm9NZ2ji6R0bEMXj7%2B9kEh4QbYRnFMRKykRAkOTq75hQzFpUQZfoHBYfolZRVJ1R2N3s3ZraEAlProtqSoXDIApABMAMzeqHY4ANQzC5YiRISMAHRIm7gzcgCCpxeLBDQ4NGtCTLhaQr5MAJIA4r64ACKX8wWd36a28RAAbLwtEQ1rYwZDoQDFu4bkilrdsPctABZJiWLQANVwACU0cCfGsdKwiERSAQArYiNgdBBJMM1gB6ABUXI5aJRNAB5ypNLpDKZLIg9hEWlYAQIw2Gl3hUKIlxoEBV0LWrHIoMYCJhAT1Wphen1ENVa0w7JmzgAQpc1s6Xc7SNgiBN6DqNnN7WsAr7/agg9bNo7znb/pHhbLRfTGcytFBpbL5YrlQbVZdgJqs9rdRbDQGTfmzaXLdqbRsHU7XS73Z7SN6IKxQwFbX61hAQ/N/TbwwDnL8ZKN2LIAKyKJzyRToWSWNYicaTbC%2BhbcRREWQKRXkJDYVg4EIQUYAaxAE7k%2Bwnczm3HvvHB3AAnLw5Nw1LJeIp7Je5OQM4KOQ84yIoIggAB26zqMcCwCgGD2BEBCcBQVA9ugSEoa0qArFoPgAO5aJCAgoUypAQRAAQ7oo8r0KUACesibuQiH2OYRAAPL0OwTGzuQOD2BowCcDRAkEO6hQAG7YBB/HYJIBSJsxihgtg478ew9KkIx1g4GJtIEH%2BMibqMgjMGwol8AIDBEKIEjSPxKgLGowkgDoWh6FpAQQZAozoBExgMHJAC0nFzOB6kFEFTgQO4XROJ%2B7hNFkOSqFEMQxQl6WpDFKUtCEn41DF9SdDYlSqMVRS9PlgyFe0DTZUVNX9KlrTcKMy4TFMPBjpO05iaBkiQms0pSSGUmvvsfDdgA6u8PzshA%2BDEGQ66fms1hYah64LOylhbjRe4HkerSnl%2BMg/uQf5XoBg2yOBkHkNBu7nv%2BN53g%2BfDPm%2BH4XQsA38aBh0weQcEIPAEAIZhyGoZQ1CIbDOErMJD5yABNBkcElHUfxdGMSprGYexjDcbxYmCcJon8YQknGDJcnAQpSlMoTakacB3k6aQDF6dMwGGcZpk2YwLAcFw1nmfZUhiSon7qJo7m6Go9K%2BedAUxaF4VrCFQmTEcCy/EgrAiAR6nsJFhgxWYFhNW4Fi1Wln4ZWk8TlUkzu5XEjvtfoUW1PQpXlO7iV%2B1b1UND79U7I1IeVS1mQFb1YzdRLfUyFOd1A7IkihOCIUjSjmhrA%2B%2BzXnI3YrSQpDrXqW1IzXgIdZtIOveQF68C%2B%2By8M4zihH3E4LKEcgTi%2BL7y9%2Bv7/lnwHA/oT0vaOYOIFDaAw9haEI%2BvqFoAQuFzHI94PqR7DkTjYn4zzhNsRxZN8cBlOaNTD8SdFBAM2JzOoMpJmqYw6liS5rpLA/Mtx0iFkvcyYsrL8ClmIGWTkQBzFcorDyXlVbwH8oFOIWs5g6z1qgA2vwRBngYuoM82BLZv1MHFW2cckoO1aknT2mU4h2xdnlJhdVKr%2BxKr0O2VU6gJwGE7BqZVEihxjmUKOycuqrmThpTOQE5w5zzgXXgoJcJrAPveaa%2Bw8HLUINXWum1t7BHXHMfardRyjBOseag6cro3QAsokCD155QSOm9Tu3de791CIPYeo9x7/UBrPdxi89waQitdHg6MZ4qLAs9Lx5AZIUTiCAXgQA%3D%3D%3D)** for clang/MSVC/ICC.

**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qgA%2BjtTkxnVEQINq2epgDC6dgFcAtvRC9%2B5zABkC9bADkHAI2xSEABmcgAHdBFiE3prO0dnfkjo4wZPbz97QOCwg2wjWKYiVlIieIcnF31sQzT6YtKiDN8AoND9ErKKxOqRLuavVuz2kIBKfXRbUlQuGQBSACYQr1Q7HABqeZDLfsJGADokbdx5uQBBM8vlghocGg2hJlwtIR8mAEkAcR9cABENoCgUCAPQgjYYezhAicDYAd2ISA2AFo/k8Xm9Pj9/lcliF7kMNl4iAA2XhaIgbWzEskU3HLNy3ekrO7YB5aACyTEsWgAargAErMgneDY6VhEIikAj%2BWxEbA6CCSMYbEEAKjVIOZjJouIu4sl0tl8sVEHsIi0rH8BDGYyuNPJRCuNAgDopG1Y5CJjFplP8XrdlL03tJjo2mBV8wA7AAhK7A4GkbBEab0D1bRYxjb%2BDNZ1C58PbOMXaN/PXnA1SmVyhVaKDmy3W232n2Oq7AV2t92ekO%2B7MBrtBgeh90Rrax%2BMJwFJlOkNMQVgF/yRzMbCD5pZZiNF3FRv4yCbsWQAVkUTnkinQsksGxEUxm2AzIW4iiIsgUtvISGwrBwwQgEwANYgMecgHMeiyLNwUG8CS3AAJy8HI3BqLIvCKPYIFyOQ54KOQV4yIoIggNhb4XhMcCwCgkLQpwFBUOu6BQjC7SoMA3AcQIMLyqQxEQP476KNa9ClAAnrIL7kJC9jmEQADy9DsOJF7kDg9gaMAnCCapBBJoUABu2DESp2CSAUNYSYoxK1Np7AyqQYnWDg2lVphMgvhMgjMGwWl8AIDBEKIEjSCpKhhOomggDoWh6HZ/jEZAEzoOE9TGcicmLCiNBwg54T6Si6kzMcIR/AAXvQhmkJJ%2BSFKYEBuD0TgoW4LRZDkqgpDEDCNR1URdfQrVtMEKE1fUjTdDYlSqKNRQDINIzDZ0TQ9SNc1DG17TcBMd7TLMPCHieZ7aQRkgABwksiZIbMAqD5hxBzcGu%2BDEGQT4oRs1jMXRT7jB9r6CZ%2B36/u0AGoTI6HkJhoE4cdshESR5BkR%2BQFYeBkHQXwcGIchYMhEdKkEf95HkJRCDwBA1FMbRQSUNQNEscEbEcShNDcUEfECSpwliZZUlMTJjAKUp2lqRpWkqYQenGIZxl4aZ5nyrz1lHipcUOaQolOXMeGuZZnkBSwHBcH5XlBVI2kqChEXaLoagygloPJalsjpZlyKFagxV/EgrAiHCtTsERtQFPUZgWCt5AtetQ29aksQR519Tze1I3B7VDQDBHM0MONgyZDHq3LZNiSF2Uyebdt957VtYOnjDBOyGdF1XTdd3cA9T2ECQpBvV6n3Uz3eJbX9iMAyjvDwQcvBRlGp2z8eISnXIx7wfBVtoRhWH13hhP6AjSMHiTiAU2gVMM7TjFfax7Gcaz7A8Rz2ncxrvPSbJQvKXhouaOLX%2B6SHBAZbaXlqgCy7krKMBsqreyjksDa1fNKNyHl/KMENr5fgpsxDm1CiARYagNJRVtnFB2SUUqxDShlLKOVWB5QKqUT22xva%2B39uwQONQ6ixDDlYYuTVI4WHLotRO8ceGx36gI6aacxqZxEanDhOc1r5wWtNaRCReH9CaOImuO0Hz7VrvjHejdzqXV4NdW6Gx7qPQgM9buvcPpn2%2BniRYKpLBE2Rl%2BH8f5qAHXBpvaGuFLxwz3qRMe5BgITynjPOep0F5LxXmvXG%2BiAmEVHuRbxixN7cDkNhfx%2BFAkH0/JVaIpheBAA%3D)** for GCC signed / unsigned or with `-fwrapv`.

---

Ideal is to start with two independent additions, then combine the pairs.  One of those three additions should be done with an `lea` to get a result into RAX, but it can be any of the three.  In a stand-alone function, you're allowed to destroy any of the incoming arg-passing registers and there's no real reason to avoid overwriting two of them instead of just one.

You do only want one LEA because a 2-register addressing mode makes it a longer instruction than an ADD.

Comment: after reading the whole thing I think I now understand. Can you confirm following for me? The 1st `C` example (function `f`) wasn't optimized because it uses `rcx` again in the second line, where the 2nd example (function `g`) uses different registers there, right? So the comment `; I guess O2 did the job for me` is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: If the comment above is right. Then we can see that `C#` ignored the `G` function there. Is there a way to fix that? Can I somehow tell `C#` to use different registers for that?

Comment: @Hrant: That's right.  Your GCC output for `f` follows the same dependency chain as mine, with each instruction reading the output of the previous one.  GCC did "a" job, but not the job you'd have liked it to do. :P  It's output for `g` is of course good, it again followed the source order of operations (unlike C#).

Comment: @Hrant: No, you can't override the code-gen choices on that level for GCC or clang any more than you can for C#.  (except of course by using inline asm in C, but that means it's impossible for the optimizer to do constant-propagation, or mix the addition chain in with other operations, or other optimizations.)  I suppose if C# had an integer type that it *treated* as non-associative, the way GCC (incorrectly) does sometimes, you could get it to do operations in source order.  But probably only by introducing something like overflow checking to make it non-associative, costing more insns.

Comment: @Hrant: In general for missed optimizations as low-level as this, **the only viable approach is to fix the compiler, not the source code.**  You've already tried hand-holding it in the source with `(a + b) + (c + d)` instead of `a + b + c + d`, and the compiler chose to defeat that.  We in general *want* compilers to know that associative operations are associative, so handing responsibility for all operation ordering back to the source would be worse.  You want compilers to be able to do useful stuff like turning `x + y - x` into just `y` if it happens after inlining.