# Can I somehow hint the compiler to calculate constant expression for me in C#?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64

I have the following `struct` here:

```cs
struct Time 
{
    public uint SEC;
    public uint MIN;
    public uint HOUR;
    public uint DAY;
}
```

Now I want to calculate the entire seconds:

```cs
static uint F(Time t) 
{
    uint r = 0;
    
    r += t.DAY  * 24 * 60 * 60;
    r += t.HOUR * 60 * 60;
    r += t.MIN  * 60;
    r += t.SEC;
    
    return r; 
}
```

The problem here is that `C#` generates following `ASM` for me:

```
Program.F(Time)
    L0000: mov eax, [rcx+0xc]
    L0003: lea eax, [rax+rax*2]
    L0006: shl eax, 3
    L0009: imul eax, 0x3c       ; it literally multiples one by one, 
    L000c: imul eax, 0x3c       ; although they are int literals. 
    L000f: imul edx, [rcx+8], 0x3c
    L0013: imul edx, 0x3c
    L0016: add eax, edx
    L0018: imul edx, [rcx+4], 0x3c
    L001c: add eax, edx
    L001e: add eax, [rcx]
    L0020: ret
```

Now when I calculated them manually like this:

```cs
static uint G(Time t) 
{
    uint r = 0;
    
    r += t.DAY  * 86400;
    r += t.HOUR * 3600;
    r += t.MIN  * 60;
    r += t.SEC;
    
    return r; 
}
```

Then it generates the result I was looking for:

```
Program.G(Time)
    L0000: imul eax, [rcx+0xc], 0x15180
    L0007: imul edx, [rcx+8], 0xe10
    L000e: add eax, edx
    L0010: imul edx, [rcx+4], 0x3c
    L0014: add eax, edx
    L0016: add eax, [rcx]
    L0018: ret
```

As you can see it removed the multiple `IMUL`s (obviously). This is the `ASM` output I'm looking for.

## Question

- Can I somehow hint `C#` compiler to calculate integer literals for me? I want to keep it like in the first example because it's much more cleaner to me. Are the examples (function `F` and `G`) somehow different or why did the `C#` compiler decide to not calculate them?

#### Notes

- Here is the [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgAJiBGAdnIG8BYAKBdwygFcwNyAVAJb4Y5Fk2blJlAMzlOAgHa8AygFEAwgG4WUmXMW8AsgEkActolTis+UvIAJAPIBVAEoXd1/XYAiAQQBNCwBfHSkWaiRvXgAxAApBYXIMAEpRZnFdW14ocgBecgAGD3DLSVyAagKMADp/AMkAKnJSFHJmpEL28k6S8vIq5JqnN27OseKw/sHak1Mmnsmy8krqmrUtKfTPOihNdNDliKoo7PIAcQShEVT0zKkz3IKl3S3VofqFgA5UQpepd61EaubrSTr/aZrOYLXpvAZrDZ9bZWXb7FiHV7MYJAA===) link.

Comment: Why not use the existing TimeSpan struct? That's more likely to have compiler/jitter optimizations baked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put parentheses around the constants, the compiler will simplify the expression.

```
static uint F(Time t) 
{
    uint r = 0;
    
    r += t.DAY  * (24 * 60 * 60);
    r += t.HOUR * (60 * 60);
    r += t.MIN  * 60;
    r += t.SEC;
    
    return r; 
}
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Is there a reason why does `C#` compiler behave in such way?

Comment: Probably because multiplication is evaluated left to right. `r += t.DAY  * 24 * 60 * 60;` is the same as `r += (((t.DAY  * 24) * 60) * 60);` Each of those 3 multiplication operations could have the side effect of an overflow error, which might be why the compiler doesn't simplify the expression.

Comment: If that's true, what does `r += 24 * 60 * 60 * t.DAY;`  do?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn In the absence of parentheses, multiplication (like most operators in C#) is left-associative, so it means `r += (((24 * 60) * 60) * t.DAY);`. The C# compiler can safely simplify to `86400` in that case too. Are you asking if it does? [The answer is yes](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoAZwygFcwMACAFWwFsZmqBvK5oOaEAzM3rYAdiwDKAUQDCAbgFDR4qSwCyASQByKykOFiJ05gAkA8gFUASoePqzLACIBBAJqGAvlSqEpEjCxMwKfKqCgcEuzABiABTsXMwYAJQ8RkL8WcaCsVDMALzMAAyOQpF5hQDUJcQozABUzEilza3tLRgAdB7eVca1JW0do9091vYVeczDnR29ugaDQvO98spVq1EA7HNKmcZ+lD5AA==).

Comment: Integer multiply is associative when the overflow behaviour is wraparound.  A good compiler wouldn't need help to do this optimization because the original source is equivalent to this.  Indeed, GCC `-O2` does it. https://godbolt.org/z/Y5eEna7dP  (I used `unsigned` to make sure that overflow is well-defined as wrapping, instead of a possibility the compiler could ignore because of signed-overflow being UB in C).  C#'s asm *doesn't* check for error, so it's obviously a missed-optimization in this case, and the expression would overflow at some point with one big constant or with multiple. :/

Comment: But still, some part of the compiler might be deciding not to re-associate and fold constants because that optimizer pass isn't considering `*` associative for some reason. 
 Things can get complicated when `*` is combined with other ops, esp. `/`, so JIT may not try?  OTOH, we know from [Out-of-order execution in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67321596) that C# JIT will pessimize `(a + b) + (c + d)` into `a + b + c + d` 
(one serial dep chain), which creates possible signed overflow where none existed in the source.  So it is willing to re-associate other operations.